# UITableView shows up as blank before data is loaded from Firebase

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve created simple UITableView with couple of rows that is loading from Firebase. 
On viewWillAppear I connect observer and populate the array with data. 
The problem happens when view is already loaded but asynchronous Firebase callback is still wasn’t called - Table appears as blank. 
The table refreshes after callback and looks like expected but the delay is still noticeable. 
I’ve configured offline mode and expecting that observer’s handler should be called immidiately but it doesn’t.

What is the proper way to handle that?
Waiting bar looks like not the best option because it’s just 100ms or so and data is already on device and I have just 8 rows.
Is there any solution?
Thank you!

Observe code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

refHandle = [areasRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    [self.arrayOfAreas removeAllObjects];

    for (FIRDataSnapshot* areaSnapshot in snapshot.children){
        Area *area = [[Area alloc] init];
        [area retrieveFromSnapshot:areaSnapshot];

        [self.arrayOfAreas addObject:area];
    } [self.tableView reloadData];
}]; }
```

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

FIRUser *currentUser = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

areasRef = [[[_ref child:@"users"] child:currentUser.uid] child:@"areas"];

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]init];
self.arrayOfAreas = [NSMutableArray new];
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO; }
```

Comment: have you assigned dataSource and delegate in Storyboard ?

Comment: and share your code so we can have a look at it and understand better of your situation.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I’ve assigned it in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I've added viewDidLoad and observe code samples

Comment: reload on main thread. And you can also use ActivityIndicator to make user feel data is getting loaded because you can have poor internet connection some times which also causes delay.

Comment: @TusharSharma just tried to do it on main thread but it didn't help. dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

Comment: @TusharSharma data is already stored on device, I got it cached, it works even in Airplane mode

Comment: How many datas in ur db? can u check the performance of "for loop"? u can place the tableview reloading code after the loop.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy thank you! I even didn't notice that it is in the loop. now it's faster but delay is still noticeable. for execution time is "0.020260989665985107" seconds. I have just 8 records in the db

Answer (score 1):

After fresh install of your app, 
Obviously there will be a delay to fetch the datas from firebase.
once you fetch all the data, you have to save it in your local DB.

From second time onwards, show the datas from your local DB and concurrently fetch the firebase DB also. (if you doesn't do update/delete in inner key values of the fetching path, firebase DB fetching query can be optimised based on the local data).

If you are saving the local DB datas to arrayOfAreas. you can change the observe block as follows

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (FIRDataSnapshot* areaSnapshot in snapshot.children){
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Area" inManagedObjectContext:[CoreData sharedData].context];
    Area *area = [[Area alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

    [area retrieveFromSnapshot:areaSnapshot];

    [arrayTemp addObject:area];
} 

/**
if you are fetching all datas again
*/
self.arrayOfAreas = arrayTemp;
[self.tableView reloadData];

/**
if you are fetching only the datas that are newly added (datas that are not existing in local DB)
*/
[self.arrayOfAreas addObjectsFromArray: arrayTemp];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

if you are using firebase offline feature, try below way. (it may not be a perfect solution)

invoke `[FIRDatabase database].goOffline` in viewDidLoad or app launch.
once the observer block executed, `[FIRDatabase database].goOnline`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! How I could show the data from local db?

Comment: its seems you are using core data. but I didn't find any code that  saving the context. it take much time for explain. if u r interested ping me on  shebinkoshyios@gmail.com

Comment: I don't use CoreData there actually, I just initialize CoreData's NSManagerObject and fill it with snapshot. I don't saveContext etc. To make data available offline I use [FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;

Comment: I've updated the code sample - there is no CoreData now, problem is the same.

Comment: Just tried goOffline / goOnline - unfortunately delay is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableview` is getting loaded on `viewDidLoad`, as there would be no data in you array at initially your `tableView` is blank.

If you don't wish to load your `tableView` until the you retrieve data then you may assign your `datasource` and `delegate` after you finish fetching your records. (In your completion block of Firebase Method)

You can show loader till your data is retrieved.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! The data is already loaded because everything works in Airplane mode, I have offline storage turned on. I've just tried to assign datasource and delegate when data is already added to array - TableView is still displayed with no data unfortunately. I wouldn't like to add loading indicator because data is already there.